# Custom Exception Catching and Returning Incorrect Values to The Terminal

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, java.util.scanner

With this code, my objective is to display an array of id numbers in the terminal that one can assign 'grades' to. It is created so that it can handle exceptions and display a message when that happens. In the final output of the code all five variables in the array must be listed, with those exceeding '100' being listed as '0'. The problem is, whenever this exception is raised, text does not output to the terminal, and it sets all the rest of the 'grades' to '0' as well. I would like to know if there is any way I can avoid this and get the code to output the message to the terminal during the 'for' loop, as well as avoid replacing all other values with '0'
Here is the code:

```
//ScoreException.Java
public class ScoreException extends Exception {
    public ScoreException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

```
//TestScore.Java
import java.util.*;
public class TestScore {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ids = {1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678};
        int[] scores = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        String scoreString = new String();
        final int HIGHLIMIT = 100;
        String inString, outString = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; ++x) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter score for student id number: " + ids[x]);
                inString = input.next();
                if(scores[x]>HIGHLIMIT){
                    throw new ScoreException("Score over 100");
                }
            }catch(ScoreException e){
                scores[x]=0;
                System.out.println("Score over 100");
            }
        }
                
        for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; ++x)
            outString = outString + "ID #" + ids[x] + "  Score " + scores[x] + "\n";
        System.out.println(outString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the input to the current index of the array. Also, you need the decrease the counter in case of exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScoreException extends Exception {
    ScoreException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ids = { 1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678 };
        int[] scores = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        final int HIGHLIMIT = 100;
        String outString = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; ++x) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter score for student id number, " + ids[x] + ": ");
                scores[x] = input.nextInt();// Assign the input to the current index of the array
                if (scores[x] > HIGHLIMIT) {
                    throw new ScoreException("Score over 100");
                }
            } catch (ScoreException e) {
                System.out.println("Score over 100");
                --x;// Decrease the counter
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; ++x)
            outString = outString + "ID #" + ids[x] + "  Score " + scores[x] + "\n";
        System.out.println(outString);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter score for student id number, 1234: 89
Enter score for student id number, 2345: 102
Score over 100
Enter score for student id number, 2345: 78
Enter score for student id number, 3456: 110
Score over 100
Enter score for student id number, 3456: 90
Enter score for student id number, 4567: 87
Enter score for student id number, 5678: 86
ID #1234  Score 89
ID #2345  Score 78
ID #3456  Score 90
ID #4567  Score 87
ID #5678  Score 86
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is never thrown. Nothing is assigned to any element of the `scores` array so they remain 0. Thus the expression `scores[x]==HIGHLIMIT` is never true. Also shouldn't it be `scores[x] > HIGHLIMIT`?

Comment: I don't believe that the code lets the output remain as zero, because in the try{} statement it gathers the data, and it is printed in the 'System.out.println(outString);'

Comment: Try this `scores[x] = Integer.parseInt(inString);` after you `inString = input.next();`.

Comment: It appears that was already apart of the original code, I just happened to remove it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, another also @ArvindKumarAvinash in the other answer suggests using `scores[x] = input.nextInt();` which is a short cut to parsing the int in a separate statement.